# watson and custom concepts

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-nlu

Correct me if I'm wrong, Watson is only able to recognize concepts(no entities) that exist on DBpedia, right?

If not, I would be thankful if you could tell me what is the correct way to recognize custom concepts i.e. to recognize those that don't exist on DBpedia?

Comment: What Watson service are you referring to? Depending on the service you can add/use custom concepts. IBM is offfering the Watson Knowledge Studio to design / manage such concepts.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that.. I'm referring to Natural Language Understanding service. I was not able to see that for concepts, only for entities. Can you provide me with a link where it is explained how to design or manage concepts in Watson Knowledge Studio in general?

Answer (score 0):

Watson NLU/WKS do not currently support customization of concepts.